# Openshift Origin 3.9 - Ansible - WebConsole

Tags: docker, ansible, openshift

I do successful ansible installation of openshift 3.9, but WebConsole not working and i guess not exist.

Version

```
oc v3.9.0+ba7faec-1
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server: ***
openshift v3.9.0+ba7faec-1
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

Project web-console not exist and webpage error is:

`missing service (service "webconsole" not found)
missing route (service "webconsole" not found)`

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Install WebConsole from playbook

`INSTALLER STATUS *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Initialization             : Complete (0:00:31)
Web Console Install        : Complete (0:00:04)`

This installation pass and it did not give an effect,

Next im trying to install a web console from this instruction:
https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console-server#installing-the-console

But, after this pod with webconsole was in pending state all the time...
with error:
`Warning  FailedScheduling  4s (x8 over 1m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 MatchNodeSelector.`

---

any ideas?

---

EDIT:

oc -n openshift-web-console describe pod

```
Name:           webconsole-675b8c8779-h65gl
Namespace:      openshift-web-console
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=openshift-web-console
            pod-template-hash=2316474335
            webconsole=true
Annotations:    openshift.io/scc=restricted
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/webconsole-675b8c8779
Containers:
webconsole:
Image:  openshift/origin-web-console:v3.9.0
Port:   8443/TCP
Command:
  /usr/bin/origin-web-console
  --audit-log-path=-
  -v=0
  --config=/var/webconsole-config/webconsole-config.yaml
Requests:
  cpu:     100m
  memory:  100Mi
Liveness:  exec [/bin/sh -c if [[ ! -f /tmp/webconsole-config.hash ]]; then 
\
md5sum /var/webconsole-config/webconsole-config.yaml > /tmp/webconsole- 
config.hash; \
elif [[ $(md5sum /var/webconsole-config/webconsole-config.yaml) != $(cat 
/tmp/webconsole-config.hash) ]]; then \
echo 'webconsole-config.yaml has changed.'; \
exit 1; \
fi && curl -k -f https://0.0.0.0:8443/console/] delay=0s timeout=1s 
period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:    http-get https://:8443/healthz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s 
#success=1 #failure=3
Environment:  <none>
Mounts:
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from webconsole-token-xgmj2 
(ro)
  /var/serving-cert from serving-cert (rw)
  /var/webconsole-config from webconsole-config (rw)
Conditions:
Type           Status
PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
serving-cert:
Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
SecretName:  webconsole-serving-cert
Optional:    false
webconsole-config:
Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
Name:      webconsole-config
Optional:  false
webconsole-token-xgmj2:
Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
SecretName:  webconsole-token-xgmj2
Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
Events:
Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
 ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  1m (x37 over 11m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes 
are available: 1 MatchNodeSelector.
```

oc -n openshift-web-console get event

```
LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT     NAME                                           
KIND         SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON              SOURCE                  
MESSAGE
4m          20m          57        webconsole-675b8c8779- 
h65gl.1528f23510e2d8d3   Pod                      Warning   FailedScheduling    
default-scheduler       0/1 nodes are available: 1 MatchN
.
20m         20m          2         webconsole-675b8c8779.1528f234d40fd602         
ReplicaSet               Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset-controller   
Error creating: pods "webconsole-
" is forbidden: error looking up service account openshift-web- 
console/webconsole: serviceaccount "webconsole" not found
20m         20m          1         webconsole-675b8c8779.1528f23510db69ee         
ReplicaSet               Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset-controller   
Created pod: webconsole-675b8c877
20m         20m          1         webconsole.1528f234d3694bcc                    
Deployment               Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment-controller   
Scaled up replica set webconsole-
to 1
```

Comment: what does ``oc get nodes`` say?

Comment: @ptrk
oc get nodes in project origin-web-console
`NAME                            STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION,


SERVER   Ready     master    4d        v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657`

Comment: thanks, now ``oc get projects`` ?

Comment: @ptrk`default ,                                        
kube-public     ,                                 
kube-service-catalog ,                            
kube-system   ,                                   
management-infra   ,                              
openshift  ,                                      
openshift-ansible-service-broker     ,            
openshift-infra ,
openshift-logging ,
openshift-node ,
openshift-template-service-broker ,
openshift-web-console `

all are active

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, you could potentially be hitting [issue#6930](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/6930). Verify that your inventory configuration has master node set to be `openshift_schedulable=true`. You can verify this using `oc describe node <node>`. And you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#marking-nodes-as-unschedulable-or-schedulable) on how to change this post installation.

However, it is odd that your installation succeeded when the console was not reachable.

Comment: In v3.9 master are schedulable by default, to be sure i did the command from documentation for making schedulable post installation, and this not take any effect on webconsole pod :(

Comment: @user9177546 in that case sounds like the problem might be else where. A few other things you could do are to

1. Delete pending pods `oc -n openshift-web-console delete <pod> --grace-period=0 --force` - this should tirgger a new deployment automatically.
2. If (1) did not trigger a new deployment, try `oc -n openshift-web-console deploy web-console --latest`. You can also try `--retry`.

If none of that work, maybe post the output of `oc -n openshift-web-console describe pod <pod>` (obviously remove any sensitive data.

Comment: Any sugesstions about other things ?

Comment: @user9177546 also maybe output of `oc -n openshift-web-console get event`.

Comment: Edit in post with output from server

Comment: @user9177546 looks like the you are missing a service account there. `Error creating: pods "webconsole-
" is forbidden: error looking up service account openshift-web- 
console/webconsole: serviceaccount "webconsole" not found` You can verify this by manually creating one. Although, it is likely that the installation did not work as expected - so other things might break.

Comment: in a project openshift-web-console exist serviceaccount: webconsole
name secrets age:
webconsole   2         58m

When i delete pod and deploy once again there is only warning with FaildedScheduling

Comment: That's a red herring then. Just noticed it was last seen 20m.

Comment: The other debug step I can think of is to check journald for logs showing anything useful.

Comment: Okay i think i resolved this error but i get another :) i got this:

{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"The client is not authorized to request a token using this method.","state":